# How does probabilities cope with determinist systems?

Tags: probability

Foreword, I have a stronger background in philosophy than mathematics, but I am interested in linking the two topics.
So I excuse in advance if this question feel silly;
Also please delete/close it if this doesn't fit the site policy.

For example, considering only one variable to calculate the probability of the birth of a person:

- the probability of one particuliar spermatozoon to penetrate the ovum.

As there is about 250 millions spermatazoons per ejaculation, that give roughly 1 chance on 250 millions that a particular spermatozoon reaches the egg.
Taking the last 2000 years and considering a generation is about 20 years,
the probability one person is born considering only the spermatozoons variable is:

250 000 000^100

So that means if we are standing at year 0, there is 1 chance on 6.22E+839 that a particuliar human, like you or me, is born 2000 years later (and this only taking one variable and a small generation number in consideration).

So probability speaking, this event is very unlikely to happen, but it happened for every human on the planet.
Looking only at the numbers, it feel paradoxal that a such low probability is happening with a 100% chance.

It might be "cheating" to take a event and calculate the probabilities of causes that might have led to this result,
anyway I would like to get mathematicians views on this paradox.

Sidenotes:
To put the question in more theoric terms, probability implies non-determinism, but causality imply determinism.
The law of physics suggesting causality of the world at some extend (skipping quantum physics here), a non determistic approach (probabilistic) of a determinist system can lead to paradoxal results, eg every living human on earth has a lower probability than 1 on 6.22E+839 to be born as he/she is.

ps: If considering the world including future events to be deterministic is problematic, we can admit that the past, as being finished and generated only one present outcome, as a deterministic system.

Comment: This might be a silly answer, but look at it from another point of view. There is an extremely small chance of winning the lottery, but every week people do.

Comment: You're looking at it the wrong way, I think. Ok, so let's say that there is a 1 in 250M chance that a *particular* spermatozoid will fertilise a particular egg. That doesn't mean that the chance of *some* spermatozoid fertilising that egg is 1 in 250M. In fact, the *larger* the number of sperm cells is, the *larger* the chances are that *some* sperm cell will fertilise the egg.

Answer (score 0):

It's very unlikely that a particular human was born in the last second. It's extremely likely that *a* human was born in the last second. It's also extremely likely that I was born at some point, because I'm conditioning on my own existence when I make that statement. You are basically confusing $P(A)$ with $P(A \vert A)$, the conditional probability.

Determinism is thought about in a different way: by viewing probabilities as beliefs. If I assign 95% probability to an event, that means I am 95% confident that it will happen, given my limited knowledge of the world. (This is the Bayesian interpretation.) That is, if I judge a hundred different events at 95% probability, I can expect to be wrong about five of the events.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, in short P(A|A) always equals 1